# Communication in distributed systems - are files really used?

Tags: ipc, distributed-computing, inter-process-communicat

> *Types of Communication*
>
> *Transient* • Message only exists while communicating processes are
>   active
>
> *Persistent* • Message persists even when processes are not active •
>   Placed in persistent message queue execution of receiving process)
>
> *A file!* • Files are a message to another activation (instantiation,
>   execution) of the same or different program • Paradigm extended to
>   message passing (pipes, port files)

The above excerpt is in the context of distributed systems from some slides I've seen. I don't understand the use of "file" in the slide. In what context is this file? Is there file communication in distributed systems, or is something wrong with the description above?

Comment: It is written clearly, that files are messages to another program activation. E.g. program 1 writes a file, program 2 opens it, hence a certain amount of information was conveyed from program 1 to program 2 via the file. This fits the abstraction of message passing as long as the file content is treated as a message. If program 2 is running on a different machine than program 1 was running on, you get a distributed system. It's called an _abstraction_.

Comment: oh, thanks for example. Example definitely cleared my doubt.